# How to create an object from a function

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I am trying to create a wrapper for lunr.js (http://lunrjs.com/) in Dart, however, I can find no documentation on how to use `this` with the Dart js interop.

This is the object I am trying to create:

```dart
var index = lunr(function () {
    this.field('title', {boost: 10})
    this.field('body')
    this.ref('id')
  })
```

Currently this is all that I have.

```dart
JsObject index = new JsObject(context['lunr'], [()
    {

    }]);
```

How am I able to access `this` from an anonymous function?

Also where do I put the actual lunr.js? I am simply making a wrapper for it so I don't see any reason to have it in a HTML file unless necessary.

EDIT:

I have also tried:

Create a function to allow for using `this` keyword. (still not sure if this syntax is correct)

```dart
_f = new JsFunction.withThis( (t) {
    t.callMethod('field', ['title', {boost: 10}])
    t.callMethod('field', ['body'])
    t.callMethod('ref', ['id'])
  });
```

Then create a `JsObject` using that function:

```dart
JsObject index = new JsObject(context['lunr'], [_f]);
```

This will give me this error:

Exception: Unhandled exception:
Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'call'

```dart
NoSuchMethodError: incorrect number of arguments passed to method named 'call'
Receiver: Closure: (dynamic) => dynamic
Tried calling: call(Instance of 'JsObject', Instance of 'JsObject')
Found: call(t)
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:45)
```

Next I tried this:

```dart
JsObject index =new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(context['lunr']);
```

That gives me a different error: `Exception: Illegal argument(s): object cannot be a num, string, bool, or null`

This may be because I do not have a way to call the `_f` function when creating the JsObject that way.

Comment: What does `context['lunr']` return? Is 'lunr' available in the js console?

Comment: `context['lunr']` returns null. It is not avaliable in the js console. The lunr.js is placed in my web/lib/ directory along with my `LunrSearch.dart` file.

Comment: you need to include the script in the html, like `<script src="web/lib/lunr.js"></script>`

Comment: Okay. Now I am getting the following error: http://pastebin.com/VPEe4qB3. That is from doing `JsObject index = new JsObject(context['lunr'], [_f]);`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use :

```dart
context.callMethod('lunr', [_f]);
```

`new JsObject(context['lunr'], [_f]);` is the same as `new lunr(f)` in JS.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just use it in the function it will be closurized with the function. Otherwise you can try using an emulated function where you pass the `this` when you instantiate an instance of the emulated function.

```dart
class SomeFunction implements Function {
    ThisType thisVal;
    SomeFunction(this.thisVal);

    call(args) {
      thisVal.field(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it. Right now all that I am getting every time I try and create the object I get: `Exception: constructor not a function`.

Comment: What code line is executed when you get this exception?

Comment: I believe we have figured out how to use `this` see my edit in the original question above. However, I am still getting an error..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know dart at all, but perhaps you can sidestep the issue of trying to use `this` entirely. The function you pass to the `lunr` function has the created index yielded as the first param as well as being the context of the function.

```
var index = lunr(function (idx) {
  idx.field('title', { boost: 10 })
  idx.field('body')
  idx.ref('id')
})
```

The above uses the yielded index object rather than relying on the context being set as the index, so you don't need to use `this`.

Comment: Thanks for the input! However I believe I should rename the title to something else I think (not sure) that we have figured out how to use `this` in the function. The only thing is that it is not the correct syntax to create an object with a function.